# Getting error 403 Failed to decrypt conversation id, Microsoft teams + Azure bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

The bot was working fine till yestarday 26 September 2023. From today I am seeing an error

```
 RestError: Failed to decrypt conversation id
    at new RestError (webpack://workflow/./node_modules/@azure/ms-rest-js/es/lib/restError.js?:12:28)
    at eval (webpack://workflow/./node_modules/@azure/ms-rest-js/es/lib/policies/deserializationPolicy.js?:116:37)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Function.getUserInfoFromContext (webpack://workflow/./src/msTeams/helpers/utils.ts?:53:20)
    at async Array.eval (webpack://workflow/./src/msTeams/teamsBot.ts?:41:31) {
  code: 'BadArgument',
  statusCode: 403,
  request: WebResource {
    streamResponseBody: false,
    url: 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/in/v3/conversations/a%3A1WbgJK2VMFJ98rna-P-r4r_yFfqrfm2I5z1M30nwXUCOWy1qLzSUx7ohZErhkNLuSwTJhzoVfXqJvNsEA2RjakN3FbJ-8JbwKICzdShrSsIf2QCJHxBW1_mK-aMFzYlrK/members/29%3A19s7N49yDmzdeN0e0VANE7DyQTUrOwmDF-_rBZ-4yL5hgYf_vYHrIv8PdV8fgiJqwnOYSRyR57hmWV96OzIcXhQ',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: HttpHeaders { _headersMap: [Object] },
    body: undefined,
    query: undefined,
    formData: undefined,
    withCredentials: false,
    abortSignal: undefined,
    timeout: 0,
    onUploadProgress: undefined,
    onDownloadProgress: undefined,
    proxySettings: undefined,
    keepAlive: undefined,
    agentSettings: undefined,
    redirectLimit: undefined,
    operationSpec: {
      httpMethod: 'GET',
      path: 'v3/conversations/{conversationId}/members/{memberId}',
      urlParameters: [Array],
      responses: [Object],
      serializer: [Serializer]
    }
  },
  response: {
    body: '{"error":{"code":"BadArgument","message":"Failed to decrypt conversation id"}}',
    headers: HttpHeaders { _headersMap: [Object] },
    status: 403
  },
  body: {
    error: {
      code: 'BadArgument',
      message: 'Failed to decrypt conversation id'
    }
  }
}
```

1. I tried uninstalling the app and did a reinstall.
2. I added the new appPassword

I am using the "botbuilder": "^4.19.0" and getting this error on calling getConversationMember

Thank you

Comment: Same issue from today. We did not change our source code. The issue appears completely randomly.

Comment: With a reproducer: https://pastebin.com/RTzzsSnK
Sometimes the message go through, sometimes, we get an error.

Comment: The issue is no longer seen. @poiuytrez

Comment: This issue occurred due to a deployment issue at the backend, it has been mitigated now. An incident has been raised to investigate further. Thank you.